# Matching 2 arrays and apply changes depending of the results

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'm having trouble with Javascript (I'm kind of a newbie)
My problem is the following:

My site displays 50 pictures on a page.
Each picture has below it a button "Watch later".
When this button is clicked, the ID of the button (related to the ID of the image above it) is saved to an array with LocalStorage and the class of the button changes to show that this image is "saved" to be watched later.

Problem is when the page is refreshed, the buttons go back to their original class. So if the user go back to this page, he won't see which pictures he saved for later. Obviously I'd like this buttons to keep their new class through refresh.

So what i'm doing to try to solve this problem is grabbing all buttons ids of the page and saving them into an array, then I compare this array with the array from my localstorage to find a match.

What I don't know is how, after finding a matching ID, changing the class of the element having this ID.

My code:

The button :

```
<button type="button" id="006" class="btn btn-default grey addwatchlater">
```

The Javascript :

```
var allButtonsID = $(".showpics button[id]")      
.map(function() { return this.id; })
.get();

parsed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idswatched') || "[]");    



var found = false;
var returnArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allButtonsID.length; i++) {
if (parsed.indexOf(allButtonsID[i]) > -1) {
found = true;

**// Changing the Class related to the IDs matching the localstorage array**    
**// I was thinking using toggleClass('btn-default btn-primary');**
**// but I don't know how to write so it's changed only for the buttons having matching IDs...**


break;
}
}
```

Sorry if I made grammatical mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: `$('button#' + allButtonsID[i])` - I think it should do the trick. Thanks to that you should be able to query the button element with given id.

Comment: Hello, thanks your sintax is right but it's not working. It's not your code the problem but mine apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have on LocalStorage an array that contains the ID's for the items you saved for later, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(arrayFromLocalStorage, function(key, value){
        $("#"+value).addClass("watchlater");
    });
});
```

Note that in the code I use jquery, so you should include it into your project.

Comment: Hello, and thank you ! I like your code and the logic behind it. I tried this, but with no results :



`var idsSaved = localStorage.getItem('idswatched');

$(document).ready(function(){


    $.each(idsSaved, function(key, value){

        $("#"+value).removeClass('btn-default');

  $("#"+value).addClass('btn-primary');

    });

});`

Comment: Yes you're right, I created one right here, thanks again
[Jsfiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/02z6zdu6/2/#&togetherjs=3vma8t0vBP

Comment: the problem is that when you retrieve the array from the LocalStorage, you retrive a string not an array, so $.each doesn't work properly.

Comment: I forked your fiddle. I create a ugly fix to your problem, but it works [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/u9mLqdpz/1/)

Comment: Yes!  I watched you work on my fiddle, I'm so thankful, thanks again Ivan